# Saving selected features as new layer using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, features, copy

How can I save selected features to a new feature class?

If I do one of the following commands always all of the features are copied, and not just the selcted ones.

```
## First select features
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(input, "INTERSECT", intersecting_features, None, "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")

## then try one of these to save as new features
new_copy = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(input, output)
```

or

```
new_copy = arcpy.management.Copy(input, output, "FeatureClass", None)
```

As I mentioned, always all of the features are copied.

Comment: is input a layer ( made with MakeFeatureLayer) ?

Comment: Input is a layer straight imported from file

Comment: the selection is stored in a layer, not a feature class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to save the result of the selection in a variable and then copy the value in the variable.

```
sel = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(input, "INTERSECT", intersecting_features, None, "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")


new_copy = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(sel, output)
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much! I just had to copy the variable!